# My proof of the (quasi-) compactness of any subset under the Zariski topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Initially, I was asked to prove that an affine variety is compact under the Zariski topology. My idea was to show that the the whole affine space $\mathbb{A}^n$ is compact, then since the affine variety is a closed subset of $\mathbb{A}^n$, it must be compact. But when I finished my proof I found that my proof works on any subset of $\mathbb{A}^n$, that is, any subset of $\mathbb{A}^n$ is compact. Is this true or there's something wrong in my proof?

Show that any subset V of $\mathbb{A}^n$ is compact under the Zariski topology.

*Proof.* Let $\mathcal{C}=\{\mathcal{O}_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in I}$ be an open cover for V. Note that every $\mathcal{O}_i \in \mathcal{C}$ is a complement of an affine variety $V_i$  where $i\in I$. Pick a $\mathcal{O}_1\in \mathcal{C}$ and if $V_1\cap V=\varnothing$, $\mathcal{O}_1$ covers $V$. Otherwise, pick $
\mathcal{O}_2\in \mathcal{C}$ and look at $V_2\cap V_1\cap V$, again if it's empty we are done, if not we pick $\mathcal{O}_3$ and continue this process. Either we have $V_m\cap V_{m-1} \dots \cap V_1\cap V=\varnothing $ for some $m$ and $\{\mathcal{O}_m, \dots ,\mathcal{O}_1\}$ is a finite subcover, or we have the following chain:

$$\mathbb{I}( V_1)\subseteq \dots \subseteq \mathbb{I}( V_1\cap \dots \cap V_n)\subseteq \dots$$
Since $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n] $ is Noetherian this chain must stablize. Let's assume it stablize at $\mathbb{I}( V_1\cap \dots \cap V_n)$ and analyze the following cases:

I. For every $\mathcal{O}_\alpha$ we pick in $\mathcal{C}$, we have $V_\alpha \cap V\cap \dots \cap V_n= V \cap \dots \cap V_n$. Which contradicts the fact that $\mathcal{C}$ is an open cover for V.

II. For every $\mathcal{O}_\alpha$ we pick in $\mathcal{C}$,  $V_\alpha \cap V_1\cap \dots \cap V_n \subsetneq V_1 \cap \dots \cap V_n$, which contradicts the fact that the above chain stablize.

Therefore, there exists at least a $\mathcal{O}_\alpha \in \mathcal{C}$ such that $V_\alpha \cap V_1\cap \dots \cap V_n= \varnothing$, (which means $V_\alpha \cap V\cap \dots \cap V_n= \varnothing$) then $\{\mathcal{O}_1, \dots , \mathcal{O}_n, \mathcal{O}_\alpha\}$  is a finite subcover we want.

**Q.E.D.**

Comment: I think that the proof is okay. Another way is to show that the topological space is Noetherian, and so if the topology is not quasicompact, you can find an infinite chain.

Comment: there're several exercises on the book asking me to show that certain kinds of sets are compact, it turns out that every set is compact......just feeling weird.